# How do you program circular flight plans in GPS?

Tags: general-aviation, autopilot, gnss

In a [recent Buzzfeed article](https://www.buzzfeed.com/peteraldhous/spies-in-the-skies) about aerial surveillance, I have seen a map showing perfectly circular flight patterns. Given how precise the patterns are, I highly doubt that the aircraft were being hand-flown.

According to the article, the planes used for this kind of survey work are GA (among others, Cessna and Pilatus PC-12 are mentioned in the article).

I was wondering how would you get to fly such a pattern using a GA-grade autopilot?

I did some research and so far the only way I could find was selecting a circular pattern in a G1000 equipped with the "Search and Rescue" additional SD card. However in this case it seems you can only have a circle where the centre of the circumference corresponds to a known waypoint ([See third last page in this PDF manual](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-00760-00_0C.pdf)), so probably that method doesn't offer enough flexibility for the purpose of aerial surveillance (e.g. what if there are no waypoints over the area you need to survey?).

Another way I imagine you could achieve something similar to a perfect circle could be by carefully setting aileron/rudder trim I guess, but I doubt you could hold a stable pattern over time just by using trim controls, due to wind, turbulence etc.

Does anyone have more insight on how you could achieve a perfectly circular flight pattern while being able to arbitrarily place the centre of the circle in any geographical location?

Comment: [You can save waypoints based on coordinates.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2EsNZ6jz5E)

Comment: @fooot I think your comment pretty much answers my question, if you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom waypoints would work, but it would not be a smooth circle. And as far as I know *looping* the set of waypoints is not straight forward. Another way is the CWS (control wheel steering) function of some autopilots such as the King KFC 225 to hold a bank angle and to control the radius with the speed, but as you pointed out in a comment, it would not be perfect due to the wind.

Also a unit such as the [Garmin 650/750](https://support.garmin.com/support/manuals/manuals.htm?partNo=010-00813-50) available for FAR 23 (small aircraft) has the new [radius-to-fix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance-based_navigation) and orbit functions:

[image]

Comment: You said: "Custom waypoints would work, but it would not be a smooth circle"; could you explain why that is the case? So if I create an Orbit SAR pattern around a custom waypoint, it's not going to be as smooth as if the Orbit SAR pattern was created around a waypoint taken from the aeronautical charts?

Comment: @mastazi - custom waypoints as in drawing a circle by linking multiple waypoints on its circumference, like a polygon.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah that wouldn't be a good idea and I agree with you that it wouldn't be a smooth circle. I am accepting your answer, thank you for your help!

Comment: Any idea what the smallest radius is? and/or what the increments are? 0.1 or 0.5?